# Connection string for Oracle Wallet with a System.Data.OracleClient provider

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, connection-string

We recently went the *Oracle Wallet* way with our applications and for the most part we did not have any issues. We have a legacy application that uses the deprecated class library `System.Data.OracleClient` and we are unable to get the wallet working with this provider.

- We have a few applications that use `ODP.net` and the below connection string works fine
  `User Id=/;Data Source = TNSDatasourceName`
- We also have legacy applications that use the `OraOLEDB.Oracle` provider and the following connection string works `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;User ID=/;Data Source=TNSDatasourceName`

We tried this `User Id=/;Data Source = TNSDatasourceName` with the 
`System.Data.OracleClient` provider and get the following error.

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied (Source: System.Data.OracleClient)

Would really appreciate any help in figuring out what the connection string format needs to be for `System.Data.OracleClient` provider and if it even works with Oracle Wallet.

Comment: Why not just upgrade the legacy application to use ODP.net?  I don't know  that `System.Data.OracleClient` was every set up to use OS Authentication

Comment: Have you tried: `DATA SOURCE=YourTnsName;USER ID=YourUserName;PASSWORD=YourPassword;`

Comment: @Hambone Upgrading it is the eventual goal. But we need to try and get it to work with wallet if possible.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei that is the regular connection string that we are using as of now. Wallet does away with user IDs and passwords in the connection string and are stored in the wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't do this. I mean don't use `System.Data.OracleClient`. [This whole namespace is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d8yct7.aspx) by Microsoft. They have announced long time ago - use your DB vendor-specific provider for .NET. In your case it means, use ODP.NET.

In any case, here is the page that describes [possible connection string options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this deprecated namespace.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a couple of "names for values" from the list and the one that worked was **Integrated Security=yes**. So the connection string looks like **Data Source = TNSDatasourceName;Integrated Security=yes;**. Again as I mentioned in the post we are aware that this is a deprecated class library and that we will be upgrading to ODP.Net. Thanks once again.

Comment: @TheRaoMeister If my answer has lead you to resolving your issue, please kindly accept it. Thank you